# Microsoft Graph - how to `filter in` for a user extension property

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Working around microsoft graph api and stumbled upon this query that fails for some reason.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=5&$select=displayName,id,extension_{ID}_ContactId&$filter=extension_{ID}_ContactId in ('11223344-5c2f-4b4d-94f6-d9a4ac441d75', '55667788-5c2f-4b4d-94f6-d9a4ac441d75')`

response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: elementType",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-02-23T12:56:42",
            "request-id": "592915ae-c174-44e3-a4ca-9298e16bc3c6",
            "client-request-id": "592915ae-c174-44e3-a4ca-9298e16bc3c6"
        }
    }
}
```

However comparing single values seems to work just fine:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=5&$select=displayName,id,extension_{ID}_ContactId&$filter=extension_{ID}_ContactId eq '46450218-5c2f-4b4d-94f6-d9a4ac441d75'`

Using `...&$filter=displayName in ('value1', 'value2')` - also works just as expected.

Could someone point a meaningful lead to solve the error for elementType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is meaningless.

Based on [Filter document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter):

> Note: Support for these operators varies by entity.

Extension Property entity doesn't support `in` logical operator currently.

If we use the same operator `in` in Azure AD Graph, it will show `Syntax error`.

It is not difficult to draw a conclusion that `in` is not yet supported.

You can use `extension_{ID}_ContactId eq 'value1' or extension_{ID}_ContactId eq 'value2'` instead.

Comment: Will do it this say then..logically it's all the same :)